# Why does the text that is read in from a text file get turned into a black square and then the first letter?

Tags: vbscript

The folder names should not have black squares for example the 'j' folder should actually be joshua.murray and not have a black square in front of it.

I was just wondering if anyone else has ever had this problem?

Comment: Please demonstrate the problem. We're neither psychic nor do we sit in front of your computer.

Answer (score 0):

It's the unicode byte order mark (BOM). It a two or three byte header that says what type of unicode it is.

> ■K e i

is what a UTF 16 (notepad's unicode format) looks like as OEM in a command prompt.